# Ionic import Camanjs

Tags: ionic-framework, camanjs

I'm trying to use camanjs library in my ionic v3 project. I installed it using npm install caman --save (also installed cairo, libjpg and libpng). Now in my project folder I can see a folder named caman in node_modules folder, so in my .ts I write

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Caman } from 'caman';

declare var Caman: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-filtri',
  templateUrl: 'filtri.html'
})
export class FiltriPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  addFilter(){
       Caman("#image", function(){
         this.sinCity();
         this.render();
       })
    }

}
```

and the html file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="addFilter()">Filtro</button>
  <img id='image' src="https://firebasestorage....">
</ion-content>
```

but if I serve I've

> ERROR ReferenceError: Caman is not defined

And that's how my node_modules folder looks like

[node_modules folder]

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to set up an ionic project with caman, please could you tell me how you did this.

Comment: Could you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try changing your import to the following:

```
import * as Caman from 'caman';
```

Comment: Thank you in advance. I try also as you suggest that approach but it give me the same error.

Comment: Strange. It should work with that statement. Have you removed the line: declare var Caman: any;

Comment: If I remove “declare var Caman: any;” I’’ve this “Module parse failed: Unexpected character “(1:0) you may need an appropriuate loader to handle this fille type”

Comment: I would try removing you node_modules and reinstalling. Otherwise i will put together a test project to see if I can recreate the issue on my end. Will look at a test project in about 2 hours.

Comment: I tried removing and reinstalling node_modules but I got the same error "Module parse...."

Comment: I gave it a shot but its not working on my end. Looks like it wants me to install extra packages onto my machine for Canvas which I dont really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare both at the same time like this.

`import { Caman } from 'caman';
 declare var Caman: any;`

you only need to use

`import { Caman } from 'caman';`

But you get the error "Module parse failed: ...." There is nothing wrong with the import it is because of the CamanJs Uses node-canvas. And canvas loads binary files. like "canvas.node". You need to install node-loader https://github.com/webpack-contrib/node-loader to resolve that error.